# Java PDFBox: Remove the parent element in tagged PDF

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, tagged-pdf

I got the **Possibly inappropriate use of a "Table" structure element** warning in PAC3 validation. Table structure in PDF as follows[image],

In order to pass the PAC3 I now drag out the tables from the parent tag to an element on its own as like below,

[image: example]

I tried the below code, but it didn't work

```
PDStructureElement parent=(PDStructureElement)element.getParent();

//parent.setStructureType(StandardStructureTypes.TABLE);
element.insertBefore(element,parent);
element.setParent(parent.getParent());
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Can you share an example pdf as a test file?

Comment: Please use this PDF, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z1R-SIalxPzAHH57_Qs0zGPDV3rjoqtN/view

Comment: One question first, are you sure you try to manipulate the right element? At first glance PAC3 complains about a `Table` element inside an `Inline_Table` element, not as in your screenshot inside a `Footnote_Inline_Tabl` element. Also there appear to be other issues in the tag structure which PAC3 does not report.

Comment: That been said, as you want to insert `element` into the grand parent's kids, you should try `parent.getParent().insertBefore` instead of `element.insertBefore`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue in the code you show is that you try to insert the `element` as kid of itself instead of as kid of its current grand parent:

```java
element.insertBefore(element,parent);
```

You can make it work like this:

```java
if (element instanceof PDStructureElement) {
    PDStructureElement pdStructureElement = (PDStructureElement) element;
    if ("Table".equals(pdStructureElement.getStructureType())) {
        PDStructureNode parentNode = pdStructureElement.getParent();
        if (parentNode instanceof PDStructureElement) {
            PDStructureElement parent = (PDStructureElement) parentNode;
            PDStructureNode newParentNode = parent.getParent();
            if (newParentNode != null) {
                newParentNode.insertBefore(pdStructureElement, parent);
                pdStructureElement.setParent(newParentNode);
                newParentNode.removeKid(parent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*(from [MoveInStructureTree](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/meta/MoveInStructureTree.java#L54) helper method `checkAndMoveTableUp`)*

Applying this recursively to the structure tree of your PDF removes the ***Possibly inappropriate use of a "Table" structure element** warning in PAC3 validation*, cf. the [MoveInStructureTree](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/meta/MoveInStructureTree.java#L41) test `testMoveTableUpTradeSimple1`.

(This code assumes that like in your example document all Table elements are  embedded as single kid in a parent element to replace. For other cases you have to add some sanity checks and probably special treatment of other cases.)